# How are anonymous objects garbage collected in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, memory-management, garbage-collection

If I create an object without assigning it to anything, when will Javascript garbage collect this object? Here is an example:

```
alert(new Date().getTime());
```

If no such garbage collection is done, will this cause a memory leak?

```
for (var i = 0; i < 99999999; i++) {
    console.info(new Date().getTime());
}
```

Comment: The direct answers to your questions ("objects are collected sometime after they are no longer referenced" and "no, it will not cause a leak") are probably not what you're really looking for. What did you really want to know?

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko and Phrogz -- i don't think there's anything wrong with asking about this sort of thing as is. If you're trying to optimise some code, perhaps to reduce memory usage, this is a very good thing to know, and it doesn't have to be tied to a particular problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If nobody in scope is referencing the anonymous objects, they'll get garbage collected the next time the GC runs.

So, after Console.info finishes running, they're up for garbage collecting.  If you set any in-scope variables to refer to them, then they won't.

Answer (score 4):

The beauty of garbage collection is that you *dont* know when the memory will be reclaimed, nor should you care (unless it's happening far too frequently).

In this situation, the runtime should eventually reclaim those `Date` instances, but nothing you do is really going to change how fast it does that. Also, this does NOT cause a memory leak.

Answer (score 4):

JavaScript runs GC (garbage collector) automatically to reclaim the memory occupied by strings, objects, arrays, and functions that are no longer in use.

> A key feature of garbage collection is that the garbage collector must
>   be able to determine when it is safe to reclaim memory. Obviously, it
>   must never reclaim values that are still in use and should collect
>   only values that are no longer reachable; that is, values that cannot
>   be referred to through any of the variables, object properties, or
>   array elements in the program.

**Reference:** [**Here.**](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/jscript/ch11_03.htm)

Answer (score 1):

This is a nice reference about JS garbare collection: http://www.scirra.com/blog/76/how-to-write-low-garbage-real-time-javascript